# Node js excel export:Download file without creating a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement excel export in my application using `fast-csv`.

Here is the flow for export

1)Fetch data from DB.

2)Prepare and download the excel

```
function export(req, res) {
  let path = "sample.csv";

  exportService.exportExcel(
    {
      path: path,
      data: data,
    },
    status => {
      res.download(path);
    },
  );
}
```

**ExportService**

```
function exportExcel(params, callback) {
  csv.writeToPath(params.path, params.data, { headers: true }).on("finish", function() {
    console.log("done");
    callback(true);
  });
}
```

This works fine however this method has a drawback it need to write to a file before download is there any way to avoid this temporary writing or delete the file after download from the folder

Comment: The most optimal way to achieve this would be with transform streams. You take a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv#transforming for a basic example. Also note that you should be able to pipe a stream to the response object in express. This means that you are optimizing for memory consumption as well as having some clean code.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First Way (Not Sure) ::** just output the csv in res.send with a Content-Disposition header set to **"attachment;filename=filename.csv"**, and it downloads
2. **Second Way ::** you can convert the JSON to csv with client side javascript. Then you can make the browser download that file as a csv

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to pipe csvWriteStream to the res.

```
function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  var data = [
    {a: "a1", b: "b1"},
    {a: "a2", b: "b2"}
  ];

  var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({headers: true})
    .transform(function(row, next){
      setImmediate(function(){
        next(null, {A: row.a, B: row.b});
      });
    })

  csvStream.pipe(res)
  data.map(function(row) { csvStream.write(row) })
  csvStream.end()
});
```

Comment: It returns invalid CSV file

Comment: I have updated my code a little. I also don't know how's your data, so I just give an example data. You can replace your data with similar format and transform function if needed.